# What kind of brooch is a "topaz brooch, a bowl of brimming yellow water"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, metaphors

What kind of brooch is a "topaz brooch, a bowl of brimming yellow water" in the following paragraph?

> When I was thirty-four, I wrapped myself in a white silk kimono with sleeves, lined in red silk, so deep they nearly brushed the ground. Around my waist I wound a cream raw silk obi my mother had sewn me and pinned it closed with a borrowed topaz brooch, a bowl of brimming yellow water, bought by my father decades earlier in London.

This is in [this book](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=tSYPVAqJ548C&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=%22topaz+brooch,+a+bowl+of+brimming+yellow+water%22&source=bl&ots=wHpnCZNBmX&sig=nKA9kJo-GAt3kN2n9yKuohiziFk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik6YXPhZTKAhWIKJQKHdmEBUIQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22topaz%20brooch%2C%20a%20bowl%20of%20brimming%20yellow%20water%22&f=false).

Comment: Topaz is a decorative stone that you might set in a brooch, and is often a rich yellowish color. Perhaps the writer is describing the topaz brooch as looking like a full bowl of yellow water?

Comment: @WimL - Yes, something like that, or maybe that the metal around the stone looked like a bowl brimming with water, much like [this brooch](http://www.morninggloryantiques.com/imagesLZ/Victorian/vict25996.jpg) could be described as "a crawling turtle," or [this brooch](http://www.jewelsdujour.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/A-TOPAZ-COLOURLESS-AND-COLOURED-DIAMOND-OWL-BROOCH-SIGNED-CARTIER-Christies.jpg) might be described as "a topaz brooch, an owl perched on a gold branch." Maybe it looked [something like this](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0844/7133/products/3410b_grande.jpg?v=1444119583)?

Answer (score 5):

> a borrowed topaz brooch, a bowl of brimming yellow water,

I think of something like this - yellow, clear, round (not square) with a slightly [convex](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/convex) top (not flat).

[image: Estate Large Topaz Pendant Brooch Pin Combo by Katofmanycolors from etsy.com]

I know the brooch has a clear yellow topaz because water in a bowl is usually clear (unlike water in a pond, for example). I know it's oval or round because bowls are usually not square (they can be, but most of the time they aren't). I know that the top bulges out a little because the bowl is "brimming" which means it's so full of water, it's about to overflow - like this cup of orange liquid:

[image: A glass brimming with orange liquid]

I think it's a very simple brooch because no other features, like [filigree](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/filigree) are described in the metaphor.

Comment: I have deleted my own answer and up-voted yours. Excellent job!

Comment: @MarkHubbard I hate to see answers get deleted - it's good for the site to have questions answered in different ways. I think for language in particular, explaining the same thing different ways makes it easier to understand

Comment: @ColleenV- I didn't realize that some types of topaz are transparent and can be yellow in color, and that ignorance tainted my entire answer in this instance. Otherwise and in general, I agree with you about not deleting answers. Thank you for your kind comment.

Answer (score 0):

> BRIM (verb)
>
> gerund or present participle: brimming
>
> fill or be full to the point of overflowing.
>
> - "a brimming cup"
>
> fill something so completely as almost to spill out of it.
>
> - "large tears brimmed in her eyes"
>
> be possessed by or full of feelings or thoughts.
>
> - "he is brimming with ideas"

The topaz *(a yellow gemstone, as pointed out in the comments)* is set on, or embedded within the brooch in such a way that it looks like a pool of yellow liquid being held in place by *surface tension*. A brooch is like a *belt buckle*; they tend to be ornamental and used to fasten accessories.

Overall, that is a great sentence for English Practitioners. At first glance, I thought "so deep" related to the redness of the sleeves. I had to go back and read that part twice. Cheers.